# Gutenberg: How to display meta field data in the block frontend (save function)

Tags: post-meta, block-editor

I have some legacy meta fields in my post that I would like to display in my block. I found a documentation for settings meta fields but not how to display them. So I tried this:

```
export default function save( { attributes } ) {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

    const postType = useSelect(
        ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(),
        []
    );

    const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' );

    const game_meta = meta[ '_shortscore_game' ];

    return (
        <p { ...blockProps } >
            <h2><game_meta/></h2>
        </p>
    );
}
```

I get this error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the
> renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of
> Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to
> debug and fix this problem.

What is the problem? It happens because of

```
const postType = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(),
    []
);
```

But why? It works the same in the edit function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#save

> Note: The save function should be a pure function that depends only on the attributes used to invoke it.
> It can not have any side effect or retrieve information from another source, e.g. it is not possible to use the data module inside it `select( store ).selector( ... )`.
> This is because if the external information changes, the block may be flagged as invalid when the post is later edited ([read more about Validation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#validation)).
> If there is a need to have other information as part of the save, developers can consider one of these two alternatives:

> - Use [dynamic blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) and dynamically retrieve the required information on the server.
> - Store the external value as an attribute which is dynamically updated in the block’s edit function as changes occur.

Comment: I used this: "Store the external value as an attribute which is dynamically updated in the block’s edit function as changes occur."

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that allows displaying meta fields and ACF fields on the front-end as blocks here [Meta Field Block](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-a-meta-field-as-block/). The requirement is your meta field has to enable the show_in_rest option.